# error: request for member ‘end’ in .... which is of non-class type ‘double’

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I got the following error which I suspect has something to do with the mismatch of types or something.... The magnitude_ variable that is used in the function is a double array declared as a pointer (e.g. double *magnitude_;) and in the function I'm trying to get the begin and end of the double array, but it doesn't seem to work.. I also tried

```
for (auto iter = std::begin(magnitude_); iter != std::end(magnitude_); ++iter)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone advise me on this?:

```
EuclideanVector.cpp: In member function ‘void evec::EuclideanVector::updateNormal()’:
EuclideanVector.cpp:180:32: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘*((evec::EuclideanVector*)this)->evec::EuclideanVector::magnitude_’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
   for (auto iter = magnitude_->begin(); iter != magnitude_->end(); ++iter)
                                ^~~~~
EuclideanVector.cpp:180:61: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘*((evec::EuclideanVector*)this)->evec::EuclideanVector::magnitude_’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
   for (auto iter = magnitude_->begin(); iter != magnitude_->end(); ++iter)
```

The function in the .cpp file is:

```
void EuclideanVector::updateNormal()
    {
        double normal_tmp = 0.0;

        for (auto iter = magnitude_->begin(); iter != magnitude_->end(); ++iter)
        {
            normal_tmp += pow(*iter, 2);
        }

        *normal_ =  sqrt(normal_tmp);

    }
```

Comment: If `magnitude_` is a `double *` then you can't iterate over it using `begin()` and `end()`. Only collection classes such as `std::vector` have those methods.

Comment: pointers aren't iterable. you should possibly use `*magnitude_` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also know the size of the array (e.g. `num_elements`), then you can use pointer arithmetic

```
for (double* iter = magnitude_; iter != (magnitude_ + num_elements); ++iter)
{
    double value = *iter;
}
```

Or simply use indexing

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
{
    double value = magnitude_[i];
}
```

Then only way `std::begin` and `std::end` would have worked is if the array size was known in that scope, e.g.

```
double magnitude_[10];
for (auto iter = std::begin(magnitude_); iter != std::end(magnitude_); ++iter)
{
}
```

I'd suggest either switching to `std::array` or `std::vector` depending on how your array is allocated, then you can use these methods more easily.

Comment: Thanks! Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not a class or an object or anything, it's basically just the memory address of the first element (and as such of type `double*`). You're using the `->` operator, which dereferences that into the `double` located at that memory address (which works just fine), and then tries to call the method `end()` on that. However, your variable isn't a class containing a method `end()`, it's a `double`. An array in C++ is nothing more than a bunch of values stored right next to each other in memory.

If you want your array to have those methods, declare it as a `std::vector<double>`. Otherwise, you'll have to keep track of the array's size yourself, and do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    double val = magnitude_[i];
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `double*` variable (i.e. a pointer to a C-style array) is not a `class` or `struct` and does not have `begin()` nor `end()` iterator access functions.

You can either use pointer arithmetic requiring access to the size of the array `magnitude_` like so:

```
for (double* it = magnitude_; it != (magnitude_ + magnitude_size); ++it)
    normal_tmp += (*iter)*(*iter);
```

Or change `magnitude_` to a `std::array<double, mag_size>` or a `std::vector<double>` depending upon whether `magnitude_` is fixed in size or needs to be expanded/contracted, and then you can use `begin()` and `end()` as you have done in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just as in C and C++ raw pointers (`double*`) don't contain size information, `end` can't extract it from a raw pointer. You probably want to use a sized C-array `foo[100]` or a `std::array` or `std::vector` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
double * ptr = new double[5];
auto iter = std::end(ptr); //uhh.....
```

What, exactly, are you expecting `std::end` to do in this context? Pointers don't store information about how many objects they're holding<sup>*</sup>, so how would `std::end` go about finding the end of an arbitrary pointer that's been passed to it?

`std::begin` and `std::end` can't be used with raw pointer-based arrays. Simply iterate with the pointer itself.

```
for(double * iter = ptr; iter < ptr+5; iter++) {
    double val = *iter;
    /*...*/
}
```

<sup>* - Okay, technically the compiler does store this information, but it's not accessible in a programmer/language-visible manner.</sup>

Comment: no point to ask what he's expecting. he said it already - the begin/end of array.

Comment: @Sugar Modified the wording; the implied question was "how do you expect `std::end` to retrieve the end of a pointer array without passing its size".

Answer (score 0):

The way you access your variable you assume this is something like a `std::vector` which has an iterator built in. But using a plain `double` array this obviously does not work. That's why you get the `is of non-class type` error. `double` is not a class but a data type.
If you want to use iterators, use `std::vector<double>` or something similar. Otherwise use the traditional `for` loop

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < numel; ii++)
{
    normal_tmp += pow(magnitude_[ii], 2);
}
```